# Why is Express needed when I'm using Apollo Server with GraphQL?

Tags: express, graphql, apollo-server

I was trying to build a server with Apollo Server/GraphQL and Postgres, but I can't find any examples that don't use Express. Therefore, it stands to reason that you need it.

So from my understanding, GraphQL uses a single endpoint because you specify what you want with the sent GQL query and resolver, and that seems to make Express unnecessary. It makes me curious, why does Express seem to be needed? If you don't need multiple endpoints, then that seems to make Express endpoints superfluous? I'm only a beginner, but is there something I'm missing in my understanding of it?

Answer (score 0):

Only Apollo Server can build a server don't need Express [example](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/getting-started). I think below are reasons that everyone uses Express [read more](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/api/plugin/drain-http-server)